# javaScript- how to insert png icon into label?

Tags: javascript, html, icons

I have to display a png icon next to the label of Yourself

```
<div class="ui-grid-a" style="display: inline">
            <label class="text-ligh ui-block-a">Post as: </label>
            <label class="link toggle-post ui-block-b" >Yourself</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Javascript issue, but rather HTML.

Use the `<img>` tag

```
 <div class="ui-grid-a" style="display: inline">
                <label class="text-ligh ui-block-a">Post as: </label>
                <label class="link toggle-post ui-block-b" style="display: inline-block;">
                <img src="myself.png" style="float:left;">Yourself</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: it displays the img under the labels

Comment: See the above change, it should get you what you want.